# Obtain patterns from a file, compare to a column of another file, and replace with column of third file, using awk

Tags: awk

I am having total three files f1.txt, f2 .txt and f3. txt with different size of columns as given below. I am trying to match the pattern of file2 with file 1 and if match found then replace the file 1 content with file 3 for that particular match. In fact file 2 and file 3 are similar but file 3 is with leading zeros

File 1:

```
8841
841
526
548
547
88
98
```

File 2:

```
841
526
548
547
```

file 3:

```
00841
0526
000548
00547
```

Desired output is in File 1 or may be other file

```
8841
00841
0526
000548
00547
88
98
```

I am trying  to use single line command from the previous post  but that is for matching files and that does not contain replacing with the values from third file if match found. I am new to shell script so please give me the single line command or script which will achieve this. I am open to use "sed" or any other shell script.

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}
    FNR==NR { a[i++]=$1; next }
    { for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        if(index($0,a[j]))
            print $0
    }' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2):

file2 is of no use. Just use file1 and file3:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0+0]=$0; next} {print ($0 in a ? a[$0] : $0)}' file3 file1
8841
00841
0526
000548
00547
88
98
```

Comment: +1 this is way better than my answer. I complicate things. :(

Answer (score 1):

Using your file1 and file3 you can do something like:

```
$ cat file1
8841
841
526
548
547
88
98

$ cat file3
00841
0526
000548
00547

$ awk 'NR==FNR{x=$1;gsub(/^0+/,"",$1);a[$1]=x;next}($1 in a){print a[$1];next}1' file3 file1
8841
00841
0526
000548
00547
88
98
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid file3, and use printf in awk to format the output with leading zeros.

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4];next} {if ($2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 in a) printf "%s %05d %04d %06d %05d %s %s",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' file2 file1

8841 00841 0526 000548 00547 88 98
```

Comment: I think the (lack of) formatting of the data in the question misled you.  The data was presented one number per line in each file; it just wasn't indented.  It is not clear that choosing different values of _n_ in formats like `%0nd` as you have done really meets the requirements of the question.  I think you could avoid using `file2`; I don't think you can avoid using `file3`.

Comment: The reason is, the OP changed to different format after my code submitted.

Comment: yeah. That is true. Now all above answer is working OK. Thank you